# Spring Batch: JOIN Query in SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean not working

Tags: spring-batch

I am using `2.2.7.RELEASE` version of Spring Batch in my project.
I have a batch which is using `JdbcPagingItemReader` to read records from DB2. In that I have a JOIN on 2 tables and have some where conditions. At the last I am providing column by which I want to sort my records. But because I am using table aliases, its giving me error. When skipping alias name, then its give problem while fetching the next set of result.
I searched and found that this issue got resolved in [2.1.9 Release](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-1848) but I couldn't find the fix in later releases. Anybody has any idea about this issue and the solution too.

You can find the code snippet of query configuration below.

```
<bean id="releaseSqlPagingQueryProvider" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.support.SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="selectClause" value="SELECT M.* " />
<property name="fromClause" value="FROM MASTER AS M JOIN RELEASE AS R ON M.EMPLOYEE_ID = R.EMPLOYEE_ID " />
<property name="whereClause" >
    <value>
         <![CDATA[
                WHERE R.COLUMN_1 = ? 
          ]]>
     </value>
</property>                 
<property name="sortKey" value="EMPLOYEE_ID" />
```

Comment: This issue is fixed in the latest version of Spring Batch (3.0.4).

Comment: Thanks Michael. When this new Release is expected. As far as my knowledge, releases are done till 3.0.3.

Comment: 3.0.4 will be out next week.

Comment: Hi. I checked it in 3.0.4. But this fix is still missing from latest release.

Comment: Can you create a jira issue for this with an example we can test against?

Comment: I have created new JIRA issue (Spring Batch/BATCH-2394). Kindly make corrections if required and let me know if more information is required. Thanks a lot Michael for looking into this issue personally.

Comment: @MichaelMinella - I am getting the same error when using the JOIN QUERY: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62519493/partitions-and-jdbcpagingitemreader-doesnt-gives-correct-values ?

Comment: Answered it in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70357862/1909708